# acess box.com with curl - get a 60 days token

Tags: curl, command-line, oauth, box-api

I'd like to access my box.com account from the command line, using curl. Until now I've been able to do so using the short-lived access tokens provided by the "heroku app" at https://box-token-generator.herokuapp.com/. Now I'd like to get a 60 days token. How can I manage that?

Answer (score 0):

That app is fine for testing purposes but shouldn't be used for production use cases or applications.

As far as tokens go, Box hasn't made any significant changes to the short-lived access token. What you're likely referring to is the change of the refresh token, going from 14 to 60 days. Access tokens will still expire in roughly one hour.

Details here: http://developers.blog.box.com/2013/11/13/oauth2-update-longer-lived-refresh-tokens/